# Barcode print failed using ESC/POS Command in C# for TM88III thermal printer

Tags: c#, escaping, thermal-printer

I've been trying in TM88III to print barcode using ESC POS command.

But it only returns a HRI character.

Assuming i am tottaly wrong and I am a worthless coder. Can you guide me to print exact barcodes using EPSON TM88III Thermal Printer?

Other commands works well except barcode...

I am using MSDN's method to send raw data to the printer.

Comment: @Sarwar, very good suggestion. I would also start with this.

Comment: huh? what is that? I don't know much about stackoverflow... Isn't this the place to ask questions and get answers?

Comment: Why don't you go and answer the good things that you know about rather than complaining about the rates, points, credits or whatever it is!!!!

Comment: You might try posting a simplified example of the code you're using.  There are lots of things you might be doing wrong, for example using the wrong Encoding when outputting a string to the serial port.

Answer (score 0):

You might try posting a simplified example of the code you're using.  There are lots of things you might be doing wrong, for example using the wrong Encoding when outputting a string to the serial port.